# Apache 2.0 Administraion

Tags: apache-2.2

Is there a way to control the no of threads in a prefork MPM????

Comment: There can be only one! - Connor MacLeod --- Of course you probably really want to know how to control the number of processes.

Answer (score 4):

Say what now?

Prefork is non-threaded.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/prefork.html

If you mean the number of child processes, then yes, you can set certain directives to regulatehow the parent process manages these.

Are you having any particular (performance, or otherwise) issues that might lead you to believe you **need** to change these settings?

Comment: I would bet he is looking for the **MaxClients** directive which sets the maximum number of child processes that will be launched.

Comment: @Zoredache is correct and i want to lower them since i dont need a heavy processes